# Why is electric field strength = -potential gradient?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, coulombs-law

I’m looking for a qualitative explanation for why electric field strength is the negative of potential gradient.

Comment: How can I improve this question?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is not. However, $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ is correct. It is because of the definition of the potential: $V(\vec{r})=-\int_P^\vec{r} \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{l}$, i.e. the line integral of the electric field with $P$ some reference point.

Comment: Why do you say “it is not”? Are you interpreting “electric field strength” to mean $|\vec E|$? I doubt that this is what the OP meant by that phrase.